# jQuery: Function bound to image's onload fetches old height() info

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've got a function bound (in the HTML) to an image's `onload=""`. The function uses jQuery's `height()` method to find the height of the image, which is used to center it vertically. Code below.

The context is a slideshow of images with different dimesions, where the `src=""` of the `<img>` is changed as the user selects the next image. The bound function  is successfully called every time the source changes, but the number it pulls with `height()` is old: that of the image before its source changed. In other words: When I start at the first image, the `height()` is right. When I go to the second the height is the same as before even though it should be different. When I go to the third image, the height is that of the second image. And so on. I know that it *can* fetch the height: If I call this function with another element's `onclick` once I'm sure the image has loaded, it works fine.

How can I make sure that the `height()` info  my function grabs is current, i.e. that of the image as it is now? I know this isn't a problem with downloads or speed; I'm testing locally.

Many thanks in advance!

**Code:**

HTML for image:

```
<img class="slidePhoto" id="slideImage" src="img1.jpg" onload="centerImg()" />
```

Relevant part of JS for `centerImg()`:

```
function centerImg(){
    var offset = Number(($('#slideImage').height())/2*-1);
    $('.slidePhoto').css({'top': '50%', 'margin-top': offset});
}
```

Comment: any code would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, `onload` is unecessary. There are other viable ways of doing what you want. Not sure if jQuery can read the image's size upon loading, but in case it doesn't, you can load each image with jQuery and PHP / ASP, fetching the size there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image source is changing with a button click, could you tie a jquery click event handler to the button to change the image, and then pull the height rather than trying to pull the height in the "onload" event of the image tag?
[jQuery Click Event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: You gave me a good idea. I've got a lot going on with that button click, but I put the call to `centerImg()` as the callback for the animation that I run between photos. Not perfect, but working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since you've set the height explicitly on the element, that's what you're getting when you ask for the height the next time. A couple options:

- (I'd try this) Create a new Image outside the DOM (`var i = new Image(); i=src='...`) and [read the size from that](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/image.shtml) (`i.height`). That should provide you with an accurate height (although some cross-browser testing will be necessary).
- In your load function you could try setting the height to "auto" before measuring it. Not sure if this will help.
- Just create a new `<img>` tag and replace the current one with this.

One of these should work.

Comment: Probably just building a new `<img />` element is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery to setup the load event. I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
$('img.slidePhoto').load(function() {
    var offset = $(this).height()/2*-1;
    $(this).css({'top': '50%', 'margin-top': offset})
}
```

(FYI: That should go in your `$(document).ready()` method.)

See the [jQuery documentation for the `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this and this strange behavior doesn't change.

Comment: By 'without success' do you mean you are still getting the old value for the height?